# What to do with an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment when not in use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk env for a `dev` version of my application. I don't need it to be up all the time, but want to use it every now and again.

What can I do so that I will not be billed for it, but I don't have to keep remaking it over and over?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You’ll have to stop the instances. Then restart them when you want them.

But, that comes with issues.

Your time is better spent making sure it can be rebuilt over and over again cleanly. Why do you want to avoid that rebuilding? Takes too long to rebuild? Or are there errors each time?

Are you using the eb-cli to make destroy and rebuild quicker and easier? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html

Comment: Thanks for your response! What do you mean by "stop the instances"? Terminate them? Sorry, new to this

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to StopInstances on the instances launched by Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: As Bruno says, and i alluded to; it’s not a good idea to go around stopping (or terminating) the instances. But to answer your question, instances can be stopped (like shutdown) or terminated (like thrown in the trash) and will no longer incur charges. But it’s not a good approach - stopped/restarted instances don’t always come back cleanly. Terminated instances tend to get replaced by new instances (handy feature of beanstalk when that’s what you want)

Comment: Try to get proficient with the eb-cli tool https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html The `eb init` command will create a file in your project which describes your environment. Then `eb create` will create your environment. And, `eb terminate` will destroy it when you no longer need it.

Comment: When learning eb-cli, use a dummy project. You don’t want to inadvertently terminate your production environment.

Comment: It’s not easy. But it’s rewarding and a great skill if you need to spin up dev envs - or even if you want a beta release online to test a future v2 of your app.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help. Could you speak to what some of the other guys are talking about? Also, do you know what the costs look like for leaving the server running all the time? What is it based on?

Comment: The cost of leaving it running depends on the instances used in the environment. So, for an environment with one EC2 (application) instance and an RDS (database) instance you’ll pay the price for those instances. Have a look at https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/ for the EC2 prices and https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/ for the RDS pricing.  As a guide, if you have a t3.micro EC2 and a t3.micro MySQL RDS you’ll pay $0.0104+0.017 per hour; or around $20.55 per month.

Comment: Marcin was suggesting that u create a “Cloudformation” template. That is basically a big text file which describes everything in your environment - for example, that you have a t3.micro app server, running Django and a t3.micro MySQL database server. But, the `eb init` command I suggested will create a similar text file; and it will guide you through that creation. However, eb init can only describe the basics; if you want to include a memcache server and some queue or anything more exotic you’d need to look at Cloudformation. It’s more flexible but much harder and has no guide rails

Comment: I don’t mean any offence, but it sounds like this is new to you. So, I would advise getting used to the eb-cli before tackling Cloudformation. Who knows - you might never need the Cloudformation stuff; or you might be able to use eb-cli for the core of your service and then some Cloudformation to describe a caching layer, or a CDN in front of your app. Maybe @Marcin can chime in?

Comment: @TomHarvey I agree. eb cli is better to start with. With time maybe can to look at getting more advanced solutions such as CloudFormation for some more automated workflows or for customizations of an EB environment using [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html)  in `.ebextentions`.

Answer (score 0):

The **most cost-effective** way is to setup the full environment in **CloudFormation** (or `eb cli` as @TomHarvey pointed out), which would **fully automate provisioning** and tearing down all the resources.

This way whenever you need it, you just provision it from scratch. When you are done with it, you just delete it fully and don't pay anything for it when not in use.

Also since its CloudFormation you can **parametrize it** to provision easily its different variants. For example, with tiny instances without load balancer for initial testing or development. At other times you can provision bigger environment if needed.

If you absolutely don't want to do anything manually, you can setup **automatic provisioning** of your stack at regular schedule, e.g. only on Monday during work ours. For this you could use **CloudWatch Event scheduled rule** with a lambda function which would deploy your template automatically as well delete it after hours.

Comment: Thanks for your response!! I am new to AWS so have a few follow up questions. So I noticed that when i created the EBS env, it made a stack in cloudformation... does this mean I don't need to create anything new?

Comment: @JannickeTvedt No problem. You still would have to define your own [EB setup in CF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ElasticBeanstalk.html), such as EB application, EB environment. The template you see in CF at present is for resources that  EB creates based on your setup.

Comment: This is a fairly advanced suggestion. And, in the end, you’re still destroying and rebuilding your env.

Comment: @TomHarvey EDIT: Yes, but this is one way that guarantees zero cost when you don't need the EB environment on regular basis and which can provision reproducible environments at all times. answer.

Comment: The eb-cli can provide command to create and destroy the entire environment. I would expect that is an easier learning curve than cloud formation templates. However, it assumes the environment is limited to EC2+RDS+LoadBalancer. For anything more complex then you’re right, cform is the only way.

Comment: @TomHarvey Yes, that would be easier. Could use saved configurations to to ensure reproducibility for that.

Comment: Ah. Just saw that you added an eb-cli option to your answer. 

Comment: So, just to confirm (btw yes I am only using RDS EC2 and LoadBalancer), if I run eb terminate, then I can just run eb deploy and it will be back up and running?

Comment: I think it should be `create` after you `terminate`. But this is something you can easily check once you start using `eb cli`.

Comment: See my comment above. You first use init to describe the env. Then create to build it and terminate to destroy. Then, create will re-create it. Deploy would be used to push a new version to a running envinroment. Which I imagine you’ll use while you develop.